# while applying class to div it is working but in case of span tag it shows absurd result

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

while applying class to div it is working but in case of span tag it shows absurd result
the class attribute is working good in case of div tag

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.city {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="city">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div> 

<div class="city">
<h2>Paris</h2>
<p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div class="city">
<h2>Tokyo</h2>
<p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<span class="city">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</span> 

</body>
</html>
```

output: [the output of the code is give below in the image attached to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYlcJ.png)

Comment: Hi, I suggest you start by checking your HTML syntax - it is not legal (e.g. having h1 element within span). Put your code through a CSS validator and correct it and then decide what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

span is an inline element and div is a block-level element, if you add `display: block` to the city class it will give the same output as the span. Read more about the span [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.city {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  /* added */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div>

<div class="city">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div class="city">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<span class="city">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that using block-level element(like `div` or `h2`) in inline-level element(like `span`) is incorrect and in the other hand if you wanna have a block-level behavior from your `span` you should add `display: block` to your `span`